# Swift NSUserdefaults twice to save

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm making a game with collisions.
when the player interacts with a wall its running the set objects and set the current object + 1.

but for some reason i have to touch the wall 2 times before it saves it.

Here is my save and load code.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("map") + 1, forKey: "map")

var myObject = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("key")
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you're needing to save to user defaults upon a game event like collision. That has a very bad code smell. Regardless, try synchronizing (the synchronize method). Just setting an object does not necessarily cause it to be written out right then and there.

Comment: ok thanks! it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling:

`NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()`

> The synchronize method, which is automatically invoked at periodic
>   intervals, keeps the in-memory cache in sync with a user’s defaults
>   database.

Calling it frequently may cause performance issues, but it's not an overkill if it's a small application OR if you really need your plist to be up to date with the changes made in the current thread or changes made in some other thread in the application.